# Глобальная переменная javaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Как на джаваскрипте сделать так, чтобы задать в нем цену товара и менять ее только в самом скрипте, и чтобы одновременно с этим она менялась во всех нужных местах?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript и HTML сами по себе никак не связаны: есть только набор тегов script, которые указывают на файлы js. На этом "обязательная" связь заканчивается.

Обычно для вашей задачи применяют библиотеки типа angular или ember, которые реализуют MVC-паттерн. Однако сразу предупреждаю, что они будут на порядок сложнее, чем jQuery и применяются для построения большого приложения, в котором связка js - отображаемые данные в html является просто компонентом и одной из основ для построения этого приложения.

Легкий и правильный путь, когда кроме вышеописанного функционала ничего не нужно, в целом будет выглядеть так:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="product" data-product-id="35">
    ...
    <div class="price">
        <span role="price-value">36.6</span> <span role="price-currency">рублей</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS (на основе jQuery):**

```
function Product(id) {
    var price;
    var currency;
    function init() {
        price = $('[data-product-id="'+id+'"] [role="price-value"]').text();
        currency = $('[data-product-id="'+id+'"] [role="price-currency"]').text();
    };
    this.updatePrice = function(_price, _currency) {
        _currency = _currency || currency;
        $('[data-product-id="'+id+'"] [role="price-value"]').text(_price);
        $('[data-product-id="'+id+'"] [role="price-currency"]').text(_currency);
        currency = _currency;
        price = _price;
    };
    this.getPrice = function() {return price;};
    this.getCurrency = function() {return currency;};
    init();
}
var product = new Product(35);
product.updatePrice(70, '$');
```

После этого остается только дергать product.updatePrice, который обновит одновременно и данные в инстансе, и на странице, достаточно лишь верно указывать атрибуты data-* и role. NB: здесь нет разделения логики и представления, что в конечном счете приведет к каше.

[пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UFtW/2/)